# Python selenium: Need help in selection using ActionChains

Tags: python, selenium

How to select these 2 devices using ActionChains?

Click and hold some place near B1 and dragging the selection till some offset after B2 to select B1 and B2.

Need to select 2 devices BL1 and BL2.
Xpath for them:

BL1:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    ".//*[@class='n9k healthscore90 sb-node']//*[@class='sb-node-display-text'][text()='BL-1']/..//*[@class='sb-node-display-icon']")
```

BL2:

```
dropdown1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    ".//*[@class='n9k healthscore90 sb-node']//*[@class='sb-node-display-text'][text()='BL-2']/..//*[@class='sb-node-display-icon']")
```

Tried:

```
a = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(dropdown).move_by_offset(-100,-100).click_and_hold().perform()
```

This helps us to hold some place near B1.

How to drag this point till B2 and select these devices?

I tried the following, but got this error:

```
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(dropdown).move_by_offset(-100,-100).click_and_hold().perform()
actionChains.move_to_element(dropdown1).perform()

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: UnknownError: Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button.'UnknownError: Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button.' when calling method: [wdIMouse::down]
```

Since, this page is not a public site, I am not able to share the link.

Comment: can you share the link as well

Comment: I noticed that you have a click_and_hold() action followed immediately by a move-and-click action. The error you're getting indicates that the second click action is illegal because the first click_and_hold has not been released. It should work as you hope by removing the click() action in the second action chain.